# Find height and width of appended image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    $('#vid_c_'+i).append('<div class="move_2" id="vd'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#vd'+i).append('<img class="class" id="id_'+i+'" src="'+_m[i-1]+'">');
    $("#id_"+i).load(function() {
         var mv_pstimg = document.getElementById('id_'+i);
         var width = mv_pstimg.clientWidth;
         var height = mv_pstimg.clientHeight;
         console.log(height +"   "+width);
    });
}
```

console outputs: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null`

FYI: The image is loaded fine in my browser

I also tried

```
$("img").one("load", function() {
  var mv_pstimg = document.getElementById('id_'+i);
  var width = mv_pstimg.clientWidth;
  var height = mv_pstimg.clientHeight;
  console.log(height +"   "+width);
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). The problem is follow:

`jQuery` **load** function is `asyncronous`.

The `callback` function passed to .load will only run when the image is loaded.

Each of the callbacks function for `load` method you're creating closes over the `loop` `i` value, not the value of `i` variable when the callback was created.

```
for(var i=1;i<10;i++){
    $('#vid_c_'+i).append('<div class="move_2" id="vd'+i+'"></div>');
    $('#vd'+i).append('<img class="class" id="id_'+i+'" src="'+_m[i-1]+'">');

    (function(index){
       $("#id_"+index).load(function() {
          var mv_pstimg = document.getElementById('id_'+index);
          var width = mv_pstimg.clientWidth;
          var height = mv_pstimg.clientHeight;
          console.log(height +"   "+width);
       });
    }(i));
}
```